# RPGLE code to RPG - Count number of Digits

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I am having an issue with coding this, I need some similar code with this but written in RPG to count the digits in a number.

NumField (15, 0) packed decimal

EVAL      numDig = %len(%trim(%char(NumField)))

Comment: what is the issue with the code? And you do not need %trim in this case since %char returns a varying string.

Comment: @RockBoro Hi! thanks for the reply. The issue is that there's no built-in function in RPGIII, that written code is from RPGIV and I need a similar code to write in RPGIII

Comment: You can usually convert the code to RPG IV pretty seamlessly with CVTRPGSRC then you can use the code you have.  Sticking with RPG III makes no sense anymore as RPG IV came out almost 30 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fun challenge.

@zen, I agree with others. I would not try to code this in RPG III. I would either convert the RPG III program to RPG IV, or I would call an RPG IV program to do this calculation.

But here is some RPG III code that gets the number of digits. It is horrible code, and almost completely untested. I would never use this code or recommend that anyone else use this code.

```
 C                     Z-ADD1.2       NUM     52
 C                     EXSR SUB1
 C                     Z-ADD-123.45   NUM     52
 C                     EXSR SUB1
 C                     Z-ADD0         NUM     52
 C                     EXSR SUB1
 C                     RETRN
 C           SUB1      BEGSR
 C                     MOVELNUM       STR    30 P
 C           '0':' '   XLATESTR       STR2   30 P
 C           ' '       CHECKSTR2      P       50
 C           P         IFGT 0
 C                     SUBSTSTR2:P    STR3   30 P
 C           ' '       CHEKRSTR3      P       50
 C                     ENDIF
 C           P         DSPLY
 C                     ENDSR
```

It displays 2, 5, 0.

Comment: I am tempted to vote down my own answer ...

Comment: Hi! Hope this code works. I would really need this at my work since I cannot just convert RPG to RPGLE.

Comment: Hi @Barbara, it works with numbers with decimals. But when I tried when the number is 1000000, it just outputs one.

Comment: Maybe you can use %TRIML instead of %TRIM.

Comment: But even if you cannot convert RPG to RPGLE, you should be able to call an RPGLE program.

Comment: Wait ... %TRIML is not available in RPG. 

@Zen, I don't know what changes you would have to make for a value like 1000000.

Answer (score 2):

the `%editc` built in function dates back to the begin of time.  So does `%len`, `%trim` and varying fields.

```
** ---------------------- test0003r --------------------------- 
dtest0003r        pi                                            
                                                                
d errmsg          s            256a                             
d packNum         s             15p 0                           
d lx              s             10i 0                           
d v20             s             20a   varying                   
d ch50            s             50a                             
 /free                                                          
      packNum     = 32553;                                      
      v20         = %trim(%editc(packNum:'Z')) ;                
      lx          = %len(v20) ;                                 
      ch50        = %trim(%editc(lx:'Z')) + ' ' + v20 ;         
      dsply       ch50 ;                                        
                                                                
      *inlr       = '1' ;                                       
      return ;                                                  
                                                                
 /end-free
```

Comment: Hi bro! Thanks for the effort man. But I need a code for RPGIII